# JMeter - multi-page submit?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a site that i need to test with JMeter that includes a multi-page submit process.

The first page contains name/address/etc.

The second page includes a file upload that is dependent on the previous page's submission.

Does anyone have any clue as to how to accomplish this with JMeter?

## Update

I actually didn't know about the [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). This maintains the session across pages, which is what our app does.  Once I did this, everything worked fine.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems pretty straight forward. Your test plan will look something like following.

- Thread group

  - HTTP Sampler 1 (Reuest the page that contains names/address etc)

    - (one ore more) Regular Expression extractor post processor (Extract the needed field.
  - HTTP Sampler 2 (2nd request with file upload, use the variable from the previous sampler post processor)
  - Tree view listener (To see whats going on)

You may find following screencasts helpful.

http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-e1bad3ad-61cf-4620-9733-e44a74af8a3e/t/jmeter-tutorial-regex-extractor-basics

http://my.kpoint.com/kapsule/gcc-1dadaeee-1572-4c83-81fc-8d401cade743/t/jmeter-tutorial-multivalue-regex